# Django Forms or own html forms?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Is it a good practice to write own forms in django templates isntead of creating built-in django forms?
 Like this:

```
<div  class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
        <div class="col-4">
             <form method="post" >
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">UserName</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="username" name="{{ form.username.name }}"
                       class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password1">Password</label><br>
                <input type="password"  id="password1" placeholder="password"
                       name="{{ form.password1.name }}" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password2">Password</label><br>
                <input type="password"  id="password2" placeholder="password" name="{{ form.password2.name }}"
                       class="form-control"> <span id="help"></span>
            </div>
            <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary form-control" value="Send">
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Django's docs say the following about their role in form creation:

- "preparing and restructuring data to make it ready for rendering"
- "creating HTML forms for the data"
- "receiving and processing submitted forms and data from the client"

source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/

If you want to let them do the heavy lifting and manage those three things listed above then why not? No need to re-invent the wheel unless you are doing something that requires it. It really depends on what you're building.

Answer (score 1):

As a heavy user of django and its forms. I recommend django forms with [django-crispy-forms.](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) This is the best package you can use to customize a form by functionality and/or layout. They have ready template forms for bootstrap too which I use for most of my projects.

Hope this helps!